# How to create a .o file in a specific folder - Makefile?

Tags: c++, makefile

### Problem :

I need to create .o files in a specific folder. But right know they are just been created in the same folder as my main.cpp.

### Makefile :

```
cversion = -std=c++23
true = 1
false = 0
notfalse = 1
ClassPath = ./test
dotO = ./dotO

output.exe: message.o main.o
    g++ $(cversion) main.o message.o -o output

main.o: main.cpp
    g++ $(cversion) -c main.cpp

message.o: message.cpp
    g++ $(cversion) -c message.cpp

clean:
    @cls
    @echo Errasing...
    @del *.o 
    @del output.exe
    @echo Files have been erased.
```

### message.h :

```
int messageBox(int x, int y);
```

### message.cpp :

```
int messageBox(int x, int y){
    return x+y;
}
```

### main.cpp :

```
#include <iostream>
#include "message.h"

int main(){
    std::cout << messageBox(10, 50) << std::endl;
}
```

### Important details :

```
OS : Windows
Text Editor : VScode
I am using mingw64
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want them in a specific folder, you need to put them there and use them from there.  So to put them in a folder called `folder` you need something like:

```
output.exe: folder/message.o folder/main.o
    g++ $(cversion) folder/main.o folder/message.o -o output

folder/main.o: main.cpp
    g++ $(cversion) -c main.cpp -o $@

folder/message.o: message.cpp
    g++ $(cversion) -c message.cpp -o $@
```

The above just adds `folder/` every time a name for a file that should be in folder is mentioned.  You can simplify that a bit by GNU-make using a pattern rule (if you're using GNU make) and `$^` to avoid repeating all the dependencies

```
output.exe: folder/message.o folder/main.o
    g++ $(cversion) $^ -o output

folder/%.o: %.cpp
    g++ $(cversion) -c $< -o $@
```

These use the single character "helper" variables that are defined in every rule:

- `$@` the target of the current rule
- `$^` the dependencies of the current rule
- `$<` the first dependency of the current rule

Comment: Hi, @Chris Dodd, when I tried this `output.exe: ./dotO/message.o ./dotO/main.o
 g++ $(cversion) main.o message.o -o output

./dotO/main.o: main.cpp
 g++ $(cversion) -c main.cpp -o $@

./dotO/message.o: message.cpp
 g++ $(cversion) -c message.cpp -o $@`

Comment: I got `g++ -std=c++23 main.o message.o -o output
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find main.o: No such file or directory
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find message.o: No such file or directory
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make: *** [makefile:9: output.exe] Error 1`

Comment: I tried without the ./ but it is the same result.

Comment: But the file are being created in the ./dotO.

Comment: You need to specify the directory in the command as well as in the dependencies.  Using `$^` will automatically get the full string from the dependency.  You need to use the full path everywhere, consistently.  If you add the folder in some places and not in others, it won't work.

Comment: Ok thank you! It worked after I putted `output.exe: dotO/message.o dotO/main.o
 g++ $(cversion) $^ -o output` Like you said. But my advice is write it on the answer directly, like do not make two section, put the full answer in one block of code for the next people.

Answer (score 1):

### $^ and $@ in simple word

**Example:**

```
Test.o: Test.cpp
    g++ -c $^ -o $@
```

- `$^` mean : the right arguments (In the example, Test.cpp)
- `$@` mean : the left arguments (In the example, Test.o)

Same things if you have two argument or more:

```
output.exe: main.o message.o
    g++ $(cversion) $^ -o $@
```

`$^` = main.o message.o (The right arguments)

`$@` = output.exe (The left arguments)

Comment: Actually, `$^` resolves to a list of _all_ the dependencies (except order-only dependencies), and `$@` resolves to the name of what's being built.   So, if in the example above, You had `Test.o: Test.cpp Test.h`, then `$^` would resolve to `Test.cpp Test.h`, which would break your recipe...    An alternative is to use `$<`.   See [automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html) in the gnu make manual.

Comment: Ok but Test.cpp and Test.h are the right arguments, that mean that what I said is true.

Comment: Your recipe would expand to `g++ Test.cpp Test.h -o output.exe`, at which point g++ would complain about the `Test.h` parameter.   If you used `$<`, it would expand to something that might work.   Also, these are not arguments, but rather the target and dependencies.

Comment: @HardcoreHenry How do you deal with your header file? Me I put them in the include folder and when I build a file, I put `-I src/include -L src/lib` after `g++`. Is your way better than mine?(I am asking this to learn)

Comment: `$<` is the correct option.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat No I am talking about header file, like how you make the links to the header file and the .cpp who need the content. Me I do #include <folder/test.h> and the test.cpp is linked in the Makefile.

Comment: Mhm, I wasn't answering to your last comment, just confirming what others already said about `$<`.

Comment: No, this is a seperate thing.   The makefile declares _dependencies_.   So if you have the line `Test.o : Test.cpp Test.h`, then `Test.o` will be rebuilt if either `Test.cpp` or `Test.h` are modified.   With just `Test.o : Test.cpp`, then if you modify `Test.h`, then `Test.o` may not be considered out of date, and therefore not recompiled, even though it might need it (regardless of the fact that Test.cpp includes Test.h...)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Ok, I didn't know.

Comment: Ok, because I saw Test.h, like I was thinking you were compiling the .h to a .o file and that you do not use include.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to @ChrisDodd's example above, a common convention is to use a variable for the destination folder, and then generate a list of objects, as so:

```
OBJ_DIR := folder
SRCS := main.cpp message.cpp
OBJS := $(patsubst %.cpp,$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o,$(notdir $(SRCS))

$(info Note: OBJS is $(OBJS))

output.exe: $(OBJS)
    g++ $(cversion) $(OBJS) -o $@

$(OBJS) : $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o : %.cpp
    g++ $(cversion) -c $< -o $@
```

Comment: Can you add more explaination, I do not undetstand the line of the variable OBJS and the 2 last line?

Comment: It's a [static pattern](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-Pattern.html) rule.   The same thing as a pattern rule, but you specify the set of targets it applies to.   See the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-Usage.html) for more details. on this.   See [automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html) for information on `$@`, `$<`, and `$^`.